# IN/OUT Network traffic not balanced on Nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, networking, reverse-proxy, network-traffic

I have a reverse proxy server configured using Nginx and proxy_pass with https.

This graph is rendered using SNMPD installed on the server.

But send/receive network traffic is not balanced. Do you know why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because a request is a small package and the answer can be gigabytes (file download) or vice versa when files are uploaded.
It really depends on the details which you did not supply.

Comment: Traffic is mainly downloading huge (500MB-8GB) files. Clients download large files through this proxy server from some origin servers. So this server grabs chunks of a file from origin servers and sends them to the client.

Comment: Does the server have multiple interfaces, which of them are taken into account? Where lies the content? Local or remote? It's too little information to make a proper statement, it's more a guess.

Comment: Server has one network interface. Content files are on multiple remote servers (origins). Clients connect to this nginx server to download. Maybe nginx grabs more chunks from origins but discards them!

Comment: Maybe you should share your configuration and like I said more details. It could be that you enabled gzip for client responses but not for `proxy_pass`. `gzip_proxied` is default to `off`. That could explain bigger inbound traffic than outbound traffic.